# Múltiples puertos abiertos para una IP conectándose a servidor en el puerto 8080

Tags: ubuntu, seguridad, glassfish, ubuntu-server

Tenemos un servidor corriendo:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (EOL)
- Glassfish 3.1.2 en el puerto 8080

Tengo una duda:

Hay una ip que se conecta al puerto `8080` con la conexión en estado `ESTABLISHED` a través de múltiples puertos, por ejemplo del `50805`, `50808`, `50809`, `50810`, `50811`, `50812`, hasta llegar al `50824`. Todas al mismo tiempo.

¿Es esto un problema? Hubo una IP que se tenía mas de 68 conexiones del mismo tipo, abriendo una cantidad grande de puertos y tuvimos que bloquearlo por medio de firewall.

Comment: ¿Todos estaban en `ESTABLISHED`? ¿o había varios en `TIME_WAIT`, `CLOSE_WAIT`, `FIN_WAIT2`, etc? Los puertos remotos es normal que sean diferentes (y prácticamente consecutivos) ya que es así como el sistema operativo selecciona el próximo puerto fuente de una conexión a un mismo puerto destino. En caso contrario no habría forma de diferenciar una conexión de otra (recuerda que se hace mediante el cuarteto IP/puerto fuente, IP/puerto destino).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias por responder con esa información, claro todos los puertos estaban en ESTABLISHED. Lo que me preocupó fue que al mismo tiempo, una sola ip de un cliente tenia tantos puertos conectados a nuestro puerto 8080, y todas en ESTABLISHED, como mencioné en mi pregunta, esa sola ip tenia 68 conexiones.

Comment: El parámetro `max-pool-size` está por defecto configurado a 32, no sería posible tener 68 conexiones si no están esperando hueco en el pool a ser atendidas. Eso provoca un ataque de denegación de servicio si intencionadamente bloquean el tráfico de esas conexiones para no enviar ni tan siquiera la cabecera de petición HTTP. ¿Qué te dice el log de acceso? ¿A qué recursos tratan de acceder? También podría ser un ataque de fuerza bruta para sacar alguna credencial de acceso. Hay herramientas como `fail2ban` que pueden ayudarte a mitigar esos ataques.

Comment: @OscarGarcia reviso el log de Glassfish, pero no botaba ningún resultado, lo que me hizo pensar en un ataque DOS, porque ni yo pude entrar cuando lo intente; a lo que se intenta acceder es a una aplicación web escrita en Java 1.7, de hecho estamos teniendo problemas con algunos clientes que son echados de la plataforma como si ellos hubiesen optado por cerrar el navegador en medio de una descarga de archivos que nosotros mismos damos.

Comment: En ese caso te recomiendo que hagas uso de un servidor web frontal que se encargue de recibir las conexiones y no tenga limitación en cuanto al número de conexiones. un ejemplo podría ser apache con el módulo [`mpm_event`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/mod/event.html), nginx o haproxy. Son capaces de recibir y mantener cientos de miles de conexiones sin completar envío de cabeceras HTTP sin apenas consumir memoria y, por supuesto, sin enviar las peticiones al backend, mitigando el ataque DoS. Otra solución es poner tu servidor tras un CDN como [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/).

Comment: Cloudflare funciona exactamente igual que poner un servidor web frontal como te he recomendado, pero además te da caché de archivos estáticos distribuida, seguridad a nivel de aplicación (anti-bots, antiDoS, etc), aunque la versión gratuita sólo funciona con el puerto 80. Si quieres que te funcione deberás usar `iptables` para redirigir las conexiones entrantes al puerto 80 al puerto 8080 de glassfish. La instrucción sería `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tus consejos, la verdad no soy muy conocedor de redes, me disculparas, pero investigaré acerca de las opciones que me has mencionado.

Comment: @OscarGarcia de hecho tenemos también un servidor apache corriendo ahí en el puerto 80 para uso de otra empresa que tiene su aplicación php en nuestro servidor.

Comment: [Para mejorar la comunicación, por favor, continuemos la conversación en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106132/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-pedro-acosta-pilataxi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo de los usuarios, el tipo de página web, si están accediendo desde una academia (por ejemplo) con una IP compartida, etc, este comportamiento podría ser normal.

Tras analizar el comportamiento de las conexiones y la falta de evidencias en el log de acceso, deducimos que se tratan de ataques de denegación de servicio que abren conexiones sin enviar cabeceras HTTP para ocupar el pool de conexiones existente e impedir que se puedan abrir nuevas por los usuarios legítimos de la web.

Para solucionar el problema propuse varias soluciones:

- Usar un servidor web frontal:

  - Apache con `mod_event`.
  - Nginx.
  - Haproxy.
- Usar un CDN con protección contra DoS/DDoS:

  - Cloudflare.

Los servidores web frontales propuestos son capaces de absorber miles de conexiones entrantes sin envío de cabeceras HTTP (como los que se están usando en el ataque DoS) para dejar pasar al servidor real (backend) sólo las legítimas.

Finalmente se decidió usar Cloudflare en su versión gratuita.

Tras darse de alta en el servicio y configurar un subdominio, probamos que el acceso a través de Cloudflare era correcto y llegó la parte más importante: **impedir el acceso directo por IP**.

Como usa `ufw` como firewall recomendé estas instrucciones:

```
curl 'https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4' | while read -r rango ; \
  do ufw allow from "$rango" to any port 8080 proto tcp ; done
ufw deny from any to any port 8080 proto tcp
```

La primera línea permite el acceso desde los servidores del CDN de Cloudflare al puerto `8080` del servidor y la segunda impide que cualquier otro pueda acceder a él.